# For loop AR model

Tags: r, for-loop, forecasting

I want to do a n step ahead forecast with a AR(4) model with a differenced time series.

**The model itself:**

```
X(t)-X(t-1)=a(1)(X(t-1)-X(t-2))+...+a(4)(X(t-4)-X(t-5))

=> X(t)=X(t-1)+a(1)(X(t-1)-X(t-2))+...+a(4)(X(t-4)-X(t-5))
```

**First forecast:**

```
X(t+1)-X(t)=a(1)(X(t)-X(t-1))+...+a(4)(X(t-3)-X(t-4))

=> X(t+1)=X(t)+a(1)(X(t)-X(t-1))+...+a(4)(X(t-3)-X(t-4))
```

**Second forecast:**

```
X(t+2)-X(t+1)=a(1)(X(t+1)-X(t))+...+a(4)(X(t-2)-X(t-3))

=> X(t+2)=X(t+1)+a(1)(X(t+1)-X(t))+...+a(4)(X(t-2)-X(t-3))
```

I tried it already with this **code**:

```
N<-50
arkoef<-0
ar<-0
ARforecast<-numeric(0)
arkoef<-c(closingkursu[2518],closingkursu[2517],closingkursu[2516],closingkursu[2515],closingkursu[2514])
ar<-arkoef
for(i in 1:N){
ARforecast<-c(ARforecast,arkoef[1]+arfit$coef[1]*(arkoef[1]-arkoef[2])+arfit$coef[2]*(arkoef[2]-arkoef[3])+arfit$coef[3]*(arkoef[3]-arkoef[4])+arfit$coef[4]*(arkoef[4]-arkoef[5]))
ar = c(tail(ARforecast, 1), head(ar, -1))}
```

The output for this code is:

```
ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1 
10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 
     ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1 
10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 
     ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1      ar1 
10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656 10.19656
```

The first forecast seems right but the loop isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to increment the values of the `ARforecast` vector in your loop.

```
N<-50 ;  arkoef<-0  ;  ar<-0 ;  ARforecast<-numeric(0)
arkoef <- c(closingkursu[2518],closingkursu[2517],closingkursu[2516],closingkursu[2515],closingkursu[2514])
ar <- arkoef

for(i in 1:N){
  ARforecast[i+1] <- c(ARforecast[i], arkoef[i]+arfit$coef[i]*(arkoef[i]-arkoef[i+1])+arfit$coef[i+1]*(arkoef[i+1]-arkoef[i+2])+arfit$coef[i+2]*(arkoef[i+2]-arkoef[i+3])+arfit$coef[i+3]*(arkoef[i+3]-arkoef[i+4]))
  ar = c(tail(ARforecast, 1), head(ar, -1))
}
```

But I do not actually understand some parts of your code (what's the `ar` doing in the loop ?)

Comment: The arfit$coef[1] to arfit$coef[4] are fixed coefficients and indexing with i will change them i assume. But the code gives me 50 warnings and NA's as value